# What are the bone indexes in the SceneKit SCNGeometrySourceSemanticBoneIndices geometry source actually indexing?

Tags: swift, ios8, scenekit

What indices are stored in the SCNGeometrySourceSemanticBoneIndices source?
The documentation is ambiguous:

Here is what the documentation has to say about SCNSkinner's boneIndices geometry source (what I'm parsing to generate the bone indexes below) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSkinner_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNSkinner/boneIndices:

"Discussion

This geometry source’s semantic property must be SCNGeometrySourceSemanticBoneIndices. Its data is an array of integer vectors, each of which corresponds to a weight vector in the boneWeights geometry source. Each component in a vector specifies the index of the node in the bones array for the corresponding bone weight component."

The documentation for SCNGeometrySourceSemanticBoneIndices has this to say https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/SCNGeometrySourceSemanticBoneIndices:

"The semantic for bone index data, used for skeletal animation of skinned surfaces.

For a geometry source, this semantic identifies data containing skeletal animation data for each vertex in the geometry. SceneKit uses this information to determine which bone nodes in the skeleton affect the behavior of each vertex.

For a custom shader program, you use this semantic to bind SceneKit’s bone index data to an input attribute of the shader."

In my case, the mesh's skinner's bones array has these 11 bones:

- 0: Optional("mouth_Head")
- 1: Optional("Jaw")
- 2: Optional("LipLowerL")
- 3: Optional("LipLowerR")
- 4: Optional("Nostrils")
- 5: Optional("LipUpperL")
- 6: Optional("LipUpperR")
- 7: Optional("LipCornerR")
- 8: Optional("LipCornerL")
- 9: Optional("CheekL")
- 10: Optional("CheekR")

When I read the SCNGeometrySourceSemanticBoneIndices source and make
a dictionary of all unique bone indices referenced, I see that there
are indeed 11 bones referenced by the mesh:

- bone index 12: 69 refs
- bone index 18: 82 refs
- bone index 9: 165 refs
- bone index 21: 153 refs
- bone index 30: 69 refs
- bone index 6: 466 refs
- bone index 15: 88 refs
- bone index 27: 170 refs
- bone index 24: 179 refs
- bone index 0: 1267 refs
- bone index 3: 201 refs

You'll note that most of the indices are outside the 0 - 10 range, so
clearly they are not indexing into the skinner's bones array, as the
documentation would suggest.

I thought that perhaps the scene stored its nodes in a flat array
internally for performance, and the indices are indexing into that (the mesh's skinner's skeleton property is the scene's rootNode).

I've tried both a depth first and a breadth first ordering of all nodes
in the scene, starting at the rootNode, and still the bone indices
in the SCNGeometrySourceSemanticBoneIndices do not make any sense -- they
do not correspond to the bones in the skinner's bones array. Ditto for both orderings starting at the first joint node in the scene...

Comment: i would like to know the answer i block there too. The documentation is not clear at all.

Comment: That's odd. For the models I've used, the indexes in the `boneIndices` source *are* in the range of the skinner's `bones` array (and in fact do refer to the correct bones).